# App Crash while connecting to Salesforce live agent chat in Android

Tags: android, salesforce, livechat

We are implementing the salesforce live agent chat in our android mobile application. Everything works fine. But we have a corner case.

Initiating the chat -> Opens chat window -> click on close button in window immediately [ within fraction of second ]. App will be crashed. Below is the log obtained from crash.

**Log :**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Session is not active. Unable to
>   create LiveAgent Request.     at
>   com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.validation.Arguments.checkNotNull(Arguments.java:75)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.chat.core.internal.liveagent.request.InternalChatRequestFactory.checkSessionIsActive(InternalChatRequestFactory.java:104)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.chat.core.internal.liveagent.request.InternalChatRequestFactory.createEndRequest(InternalChatRequestFactory.java:95)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.chat.core.internal.liveagent.handler.EndHandler.onEndingSessionState(EndHandler.java:109)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.chat.core.internal.liveagent.LiveAgentChatSession.onStateChanged(LiveAgentChatSession.java:177)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.chat.core.internal.liveagent.LiveAgentChatSession.onStateChanged(LiveAgentChatSession.java:54)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.lifecycle.LifecycleEvaluator.stateChanged(LifecycleEvaluator.java:304)
>     at
>   com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.lifecycle.LifecycleStateWatcher$1.run(LifecycleStateWatcher.java:73)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Is there any work around to overcome this issue. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Follow up this issue here --> https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000UUpoQAG

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it on my end. Hope this helps.

```
WebView wvBody = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Chat_wvBody);

String url = "http://myweburl.com/chatx.html?m_email=" + accountInfo.getUserEmail() +
            "&fname=" + accountInfo.getUserFirstName() +
            "&lname=" + accountInfo.getUserLastName();

    wvBody.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvBody.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    wvBody.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wvBody.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    wvBody.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    wvBody.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wvBody.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        wvBody.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }
    wvBody.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
            avLoadingIndicatorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            avLoadingIndicatorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvNote.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED

            webViewLoadingFinished = true;
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        wvBody.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    else
        wvBody.loadUrl(url);

    wvBody.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. But i'm not using webview in this case. Native integration is implemented.